# How to compile C into an executable binary file and run it in Android from Android Shell?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I have a Device on which I installed Android Gingerbread 2.3.4
Here i want to run C executable file on android device

I am able to run android NDK application on this Device and it runs perfect.
But I want to run only one `hello.c` executable file on the Device.

```
/* #includes #defines ... */

int main(){
    // Do something when this is executed
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to compile this file with `Android NDK` tool chain so I can run this file's executable?

I found one thing [here](http://my.opera.com/otaku_2r/blog/build-and-run-c-application-on-android) but this is not working for me. I am using `Android NDK, Revision 7b` for Linux. 
There is no directory structure like this.

Comment: [How to build an executable for Android shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35231168/3290339)

Comment: I generally do this simply inside the app TERMUX which gives you a working  unix terminal

Comment: See the [official guide(s)](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/build), most of the answers here are outdated. For the easiest method (one line compile, no build system), see [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems).

Answer (score 40):

First, let me say that my answer is dependent on your using NDK r7b (it'll work for r7c as well) on Linux (change paths appropriately for other systems).

**Edit:** Last tested with `NDK r8e` on *Linux* and `Nexus 4` with `adb` from `SDK Platform-Tools Rev 18`  on *Windows 7* (latest as of 2013-07-25) **without root access**.

**Yet Another Edit:** Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818902/running-a-native-library-on-android-l-error-only-position-independent-executab) for altering my instruction for native binaries that need to run on *Android 5.0(Lollypop)* and later.

1. Go to `$NDK_ROOT` (The topmost folder of NDK zip when unzipped).
2. Copy `$NDK_ROOT/samples/hello-jni` directory as `$NDK_ROOT/sources/hello-world`.
3. Go to `$NDK_ROOT/sources/hello-world`.
4. Edit `AndroidManifest.xml` to give the application an appropriate name (This is optional).
5. Go to `$NDK_ROOT/sources/hello-world/jni`. This is where the source code is.
6. Edit `hello-jni.c`, remove all the code, and put in your `hello world` code. Mine is:

   ```
   #include 
   int main( int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       printf("Hello, World!");
       return 0;
   }
   ```
7. Edit `Android.mk` and change the line `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` to `include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`. You can also change the `LOCAL_MODULE` line to the name you want for your executable(default is `hello-jni`)
8. Go back to `$NDK_ROOT/sources/hello-world`
9. Run `../../ndk-build` to create the executable.
10. Copy it from `$NDK_ROOT/sources/hello-jni/libs/armeabi/hello-jni` to `/data/local/tmp` on the Android device and change it's permissions to 755 (rwxr-xr-x). If you changed the `LOCAL_MODULE` line in `$NDK_ROOT/sources/hello-world/jni/Android.mk`, the executable name will be the new value of `LOCAL_MODULE` instead of `hello-jni`. (All this is done via `adb` from the Android SDK.)
11. Execute the binary with full path as `/data/local/tmp/hello-jni`, or whatever you named it to.

And you're done( and free to start on the documentation in $NDK_ROOT/docs to get a better idea of what to do).

Comment: There is `test-libstdc++` project under samples directory which looks like exactly what you are try to explain.

Answer (score 27):

The best/easiest place to put a executable is **/data/local**. You'll also need to [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) the binary as executable. Often you'll also need to do this in two steps to get the binary from `/sdcard/` to `/data/local`:

```
$ adb push mybin /sdcard/
$ adb shell
$ cp /sdcard/mybin /data/local/mybin
$ cd /data/local
$ chmod 751 mybin
```

**Caveats**:

- Not all systems have `cp`. You can use [cat](http://ss64.com/bash/cat.html) if this is the case:

  `$ cat /sdcard/mybin > /data/local/mybin`
- Some systems don't allow write in `/data/local` for the "shell" user. Try `/data/local/tmp`

Comment: Are you saying that the binary itself crashes when it runs? If that is the case I suggest you open a new question the specific issue(s) there.

Comment: Where i am saying? i cant able to Execute this C binary files. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you need root to play outside the bounds of your application's sandbox.

Comment: Incorrect, you **do not** need root, you simply must put the binary in a location writable by the app, such as its private directory.

Comment: Further, there's no need to push the file to the scard and then move it to /data/local (or more likely, /data/local/tmp) - if you can move it there, you can put it there with adb push to begin with.

Comment: Does this still work on Lollipop or Marshmallow? Seems once I update the OS I start getting permission errors.

Comment: I didn't find `/data/local` on my (unrooted) Android device, but I installed a Terminal app (e.g., https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=Terminal&fdid=jackpal.androidterm ) and was able to copy the file into its "home" (`~` in its shell). It's a place where it can be made executable with `chmod 0755 mybin` (only numeric specification of the mode worked). `~` was `/data/data/jackpal.androidterm/app_HOME`

Answer (score 12):

the "/sdcard" location is not executable, meaning that any file there is not executable at all.

the only way to "adb push" executable would be to put them in "/data/local", which should be writable for adb, and allow execution for anyone.

Comment: In Lollipop (on my Xperia Z3) I needed to copy it to `/data/local/tmp` and that worked.

Answer (score 12):

I recently had the same problem on a new nexus-5. I'd like to add that /data/local was not writable by the user ("shell", uid 2000) I got with adb shell. But putting the executable in the subdirectory /data/local/tmp/ worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

In a nutshell,

First, to cross-compile your C code from your host machine, use NDK toolchain with sysroot option and position independent option `-fPIE -pie`.

```
$NDKROOT/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc \
--sysroot=$NDKROOT/platforms/android-22/arch-arm64 -fPIE -pie main.c -o main
```

Note that the **arch part** `aarch64` or `aarch-arm64`, the **toolchain version part** `4.9`, **platform version part** `android-22`, and the binary format for your **host machine** `darwin-x86_64` may vary by your environment.

Second, push your binary under `/data/local/tmp` and execute it from `adb shell`.

Answer (score -1):

Did you ever heard an app called 'c4droid'?

It can take your c/cpp code, compile it directly into an apk file in your android phone. You can achive it by click "the menu -> exporting to apk file"

(And you can also directly run c/cpp code in your android phone by using 'c4droid')

[image]

> 'c4droid' used to be in the google play, but now it is not because the author decided to create other application.

But here is the old c4droid v8.0 app download link (I suggest you put it to torrent network to save it forever, because it seems like you can't easily download it from normal network because it is too powerful):

https://www.mediafire.com/file/wnt7txwz5296ajs/c4droid_can_compile_c_into_apk_in_android.tar.gz/file