# Running C/C++ code using OpenCV in android

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, native

I don't know whether i make sense or not. But just wanted to now that can i run the `c/c++` code in android without the need of writing `JNI wrapper` or using `Native Activity` way?

I mean, I am having a simple `C++ Template Matching code` which contains main function and I use to run it using `g++` in terminal.

Now I want this Template Matching code to be run in android usng `NDK`. Is there any way? I have googled a lot but all they is to either use JNI wrapper or use `SWIG` which makes JNI wrapper, but can't actually get into any of them. I need more simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a rooted phone, you can compile and run programs as on any linux machine, from the `adb shell`.

However, that requires a bit of knowledge about Linux.

So, to start:

- Root your phone (force it to give you admin privileges). That is easy for developer phones/boards, and a kill for regular phones bought at a shop downstreet.
- compile your app for android and run it from adb as you would do from a linux shell.

Here is a more detailed answer on the matter

[How to compile C into an executable binary file and run it in Android from Android Shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868309/how-can-i-run-c-binary-executable-file-in-android-from-android-shell)

Comment: Thanks a lot..Happy to now that there is a way..I am surely going to try it out..and if it works out..this is going to be best answer :-)

Comment: Google for instructions on your specific model. For some models there is no info available, for others you need to do a bit of hacking, and for a few of them is as simple as restarting in admin mode.