# Not able to run executable file from adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, tcpdump

I've added tcpdump binary file to my android device using this command

```
./adb push ~/tcpdump-4.2.1/tcpdump /data/local
```

The binary is added to the android device successfully.
But, when I try to execute the tcpdump file from the adb shell, using following commands

```
./adb shell
cd data/local
./tcpdump
```

It gives me this error

```
/system/bin/sh: ./tcpdump: not executable: magic 7F45
```

I've also tried changing permissions using `chmod 777 tcpdump` but in vain. 
How do I overcome this issue? Thanks.

Comment: what error does chmod gives you? you could push it to sdcard, chmod it there, then move it (i suppose). are you root?

Comment: I use android terminal emulator. It comes with busybox which has tcpdump

Comment: @Pepelac I compiled it on my ubuntu desktop using these commands ./configure, make, sudo make install. Then I pushed the tcpdump file on the android device.

Comment: @njzk2 chmod on my desktop and on the adb shell does not give me any error. It executes well.

Comment: @HarshalKshatriya Yep and it's not helps. Because you can't run on android files that was compiled with standart GCC. You should use it from NDK to compile 32bit ELF file...

Comment: @Pepelac I've tried to build binary for tcpdump using cross compiler provided by ndk but still in vain. I used these commands ./configure CC=path/to/arm-gcc , but it fails. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Right now using the binary from this blog as a quick fix. http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.in/2009/03/android-binary-solo.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868309/how-can-i-run-c-binary-executable-file-in-android-from-android-shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an Android version of tcpdump [here](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~timuralp/tcpdump-arm). This build is somewhat outdated, and only relevant for ARM devices. You should follow [these instructions](http://nerdjusttyped.blogspot.co.il/2009/03/android-binary-solo.html) to build the binary from [official source](http://www.tcpdump.org/#latest-release).

There are [detailed instructions](http://vbsteven.com/archives/219) re how to run **tcpdump** on Android. Note that you need a rooted device to begin with.

Comment: Also, check this link. Part of it explains how to build binary for arm device using the source. Great help. http://codeseekah.com/2012/08/07/port-forwarding-an-android-local-port/

Comment: The linked build of tcpdump is version 4.0 which is a bit old. You can download an ARM build of version 4.3 here: http://omappedia.org/wiki/File:Tcpdump-4.3.0-arm.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

You should compile binary files via `GCC` from [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

try the following command:

enter this command `c:\ProgramFiles\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb shell tcpdump`

for linux:

```
   adb shell chmod 6755 /data/local/tmp/tcpdump
```

and also go through this link for better understanding:

http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/tcpdump.html

Comment: I use ubuntu. Still I tried it like this ./adb shell /data/local/tcpdump . It gives me the same error mentioned above.

Comment: i have posted the answer, please check and let me know... enter your path to tcpdump file

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error trying to run another binary into the android emulator. Error came from the compilation.

You have to cross-compile for an ARM target which means you need a specific toolchain like for example arm-linux-androideabi.

To do so, you need to

- export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- (your toolchain ending by '-' without gcc)
- export ARCH=arm
- add the toolchain to your PATH

Then you can run make command. You might want to add -static to the LDFLAGS before building.

Finally check your binary has been well compiled by using the file command. You should look for ARM in the printed result.

In case the Makefile doesn't handle CROSS_COMPILE var you can try to make with parameters CC and AR manually set with "$CROSS-COMPILE"gcc and "$CROSS-COMPILE"ar

further details here: http://source.android.com/source/index.html